# Nested optgroup solution from drop down list

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, xhtml, jquery-plugins

I have a drop down <select> list of pages in a site, however the structure is quite complicated to go in the list e.g.;

- Home
- Projects

  - Category 1

    - Item 1
    - Item 2
    - Item 3
  - Category 2

    - Item 4
    - Item 5
    - Item 6
  - Category 3

    - Item 4
    - Item 5
- Contact
- Accessibility
- Sitemap

What I want to do is say "select a page to link to" and then present the user with a <select> list of the above options.  The problem is, <optgroup> isn't nestable, so I was wondering if anyone had a more elegant solution (maybe using Jquery or something) to present the list?

At the moment I am just using multiple &nbsp;'s and &bull;'s (•) to achieve an indented list like the old un-ordered list that we know and love... but it's not ideal.

Also, I don't want to use a tree - it really needs to be a drop down type list for space saving reasons.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

There are several jQuery plugins available which will do the job:

1. http://www.givainc.com/labs/mcdropdown_jquery_plugin.htm
2. http://p.sohei.org/jquery-plugins/clickmenu/